# How to delete two of every three columns using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use VBA to delete the first 2 columns of every three in Excel in a given range?

I would then like to be able to edit the sub to delete the first 3 out of 4 columns, the first 4 out of every 5 columns, the first 5 of every 6 columns and so on.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, take [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for your first badge and check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please show us what you managed so far, so we can help out. As the question stands it very much looks like you are asking us to provide the solution to a task and not a specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd have a go, not fully tested.  You need to look at `resize` for this

```
Function delete_x_of_y(rngStart As Excel.Range, lngNumTotal As Long, lngNumDel As Long)

Dim rTemp As Excel.Range

Set rTemp = rngStart.Resize(, lngNumTotal - (lngNumTotal - lngNumDel)).EntireColumn

rTemp.Delete

End Function
```

So `delete_x_of_y(range("a1"),5,2)` deletes first 2 of 5 columns

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks very much for your response. I'm very inexperienced with VBA and can't get the code to work. Can you show me exactly how the code should look for the 5,2 example. I should hopefully be able to work out where I'm going from here. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, it's already on there. The last line, so.....`So delete_x_of_y(range("a1"),5,2) deletes first 2 of 5 columns`   You'll have to do a bit of learning, record macro's inspect the code generated.  This site is for code assistance, not full coding.